# Get in to JSON all the rows from sql query in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, json, db2, resultset

I got the next code. I think I just need to make a little change but I don't know what. The code only returns the last row but I want to see all the rows in response. If I declare a LIMIT 10 then I want to get 10 results in response.

What should I change?

Thank you.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/url/results/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public JsonResponse getResults() throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = ConnSingle.getInstance().getConnection(env);
        String selectSql = "SELECT * FROM Lib.Table WHERE YEARS=10 LIMIT 10";

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);


        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        System.out.println(rsmd);

        while(rs.next()) {
            int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i=1; i<=numColumns; i++) {
                String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();

        return new JsonResponse(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over resultset and adding each row into `JSONObject` but not adding `JSONObject` into the `JSONArray`.

Just add `JSONObject (obj)` into `JSONArray (json)` and you will get all rows/records in the response. :)

Answer (score 1):

@jaydip is right (he's beaten me by few minutes).
Here is an example...
You are pushing all the results in the same obj object.
To display all the results you have to push "obj" into an array like this:

```
JSONArray objects = new JSONArray();
while(rs.next()) {
            int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i=1; i<=numColumns; i++) {
                String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
                objects.add(obj);
            }
        }
rs.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();

        return new JsonResponse(objects);
```

Comment: Oh... I understand... I need to push all the objects inside the array, but when I want to push `objects.push(obj);` the push method doesnt work: `error: cannot find symbol object.<push>(obj);` D; !!! I just know that in javascript its more easy...

Comment: Yes, I have the solution, is not push, is add :D !!! `json.add(obj);` before the for loop

Comment: No problem @jgmcontessa , but the `objects.add(obj);` must go after the key of the for loop for to add the object when iterating. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

#### Doing it natively with Db2's SQL/JSON support

You might not need to have to implement any logic in Java to get this sort of JSON document out of your Db2 database, [just use the Db2 native SQL/JSON capabilities, as I've described in this article](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/11/13/stop-mapping-stuff-in-your-middleware-use-sqls-xml-or-json-operators-instead/).

Instead of:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Lib.Table WHERE YEARS=10 LIMIT 10
```

Write:

```sql
SELECT cast(('[' || listagg(
  json_object(
    KEY 'id' VALUE t.id,
    KEY 'years' VALUE t.years,
    ...
  ), ',') || ']') AS varchar(32672))
FROM lib.table t
WHERE t.years = 10
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Unfortunately, Db2 doesn't yet support the standard SQL/JSON `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` function, which is why you have to do the string concatenation workaround yourself.

#### Using a third party library

If using a third party library is an option for you in this case, [jOOQ can handle that emulation of `JSON_ARRAYAGG` for you](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/json-arrayagg-function/). With jOOQ in a simple case like this, you could also just export the JSON from the JDBC `ResultSet` like this:

```java
String json = ctx.fetch(rs).formatJSON();
```

(Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)